# Can I use my function as `negroni` middleware

Tags: go, negroni

I have a function which I use as wrapper for every GET request:

```
type HandlerFunc func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) (interface{}, error)

func WrapHandler(handler HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

        data, err := handler(w, req)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            w.WriteHeader(500)
        } else {
            w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
            resp, _ := json.Marshal(data)
            w.Write(resp)
        }
    }
}
```

router:

```
router.HandleFunc("/rss/unread/{rss_type}",
   controllers.WrapHandler(controllers.GetUnreadRssFeeds))
```

example:

```
func GetUnreadRssFeeds(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (interface{}, error)  {

    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    rss_type, err :=  strconv.Atoi(vars["rss_type"])
    feeds, err := (&postgres.FeedService{}).GetUnreadRssFeeds(rss_type)
    return feeds, err
}
```

Now I need wrap each request in the router: `controllers.WrapHandler(controllers.GetUnreadRssFeeds)`. I am looking the way to avoid it.

Can I transform my `WrapHandler` to use it as `negroni` middleware ? Is there a way to pass data between `negroni` middleware functions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I combine Go middleware pattern with error returning request handlers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871194/how-can-i-combine-go-middleware-pattern-with-error-returning-request-handlers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hurdle you'll have to cross with using your `WrapHandler` as negroni middleware is that your `WrapHandler` is actually an adaptor, not a wrapper.  You're taking a non-`http.HandlerFunc` and converting it to a `http.HandlerFunc`.

I can't think of a way to do that in middleware, because middleware just acts on the request/response and the `http.HandlerFunc`(s).