# How do i write golang middleware which handle response/error from API?

Tags: go, middleware, mux

Basically, I want to write one middleware which closes transaction object is created while a request. I am using gorilla mux package. I am familiar with python-Django middlewares and it gives proper handling of error or response. but not able to find anything similar with golang

Answer (score -1):

In Go lang you can create a middle-ware too, below I've written the process to create handler as `validateMiddleware` then called it when `TestEndpoint` API requested.

```
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.HandleFunc("/test", ValidateMiddleware(TestEndpoint)).Methods("GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":12345", router))
}
```

And now you can create your `validateMiddleware` handler as:

```
    func ValidateMiddleware(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
            authorizationHeader := req.Header.Get("authorization")
                    if authorizationHeader != "" {
                        // if true, then request for next handler.
                        next(w, req)
                    } else {
                        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Exception{Message: "Invalid authorization token"})
                        return
                    }
        })
    }
```

And finally create original requested handler `TestEndpoint`

```
func TestEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Hello Go middleware!!!")
}
```

Comment: I am starting a transaction in the handler and want to close it in middleware whether it throws an error from the handler or returns response.

Comment: As you can see the response in `else` part, if authorization failed in `validateMiddleware` handler, so you can also return like this. And don't forget to mention `return` keyword if you don't want to execute further code after throws an error.

Comment: I think the code you shared will call before the actual handler but I want to write it in a way that it will be called after handler's response or error it throws.

Comment: you want to manage errors throwing by your code? then why you need a `middleware`? why don't you use `error` handle process like:
`if err != nil { //something to response }`

Comment: I want to close the SQL transaction which started in the handler. because I am writing repetitive code everywhere, and if I found a way to write a middleware which closed after any response from a handler. i am looking for error because if it throws an error then i want to roll back the transaction else i will commit it on success.

Comment: `func closeTxnMiddleware(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
            if w.response_code == 200 || 201 {
             if err = txo.Commit(); err == nil {
   return false
  }
            }
          else {
              txo.Rollback();
           }
        })
    }`


i am looking for something like this

Comment: may be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871194/how-can-i-combine-go-middleware-pattern-with-error-returning-request-handlers) would be helpful for you.