# Golang HTTP custom error handling response

Tags: http, go, error-handling, mux, custom-error-handling

I was going through https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go and at the end it gave a good example on how to handle returning errors in a cleaner way and just made something simple:

```
// Wrapper for handler functions.
type rootHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error

// Implement the http.Handler interface.
func (fn rootHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := fn(w, r) // Call handler function.
    if err == nil {
        return
    }

    ...
}
```

```
// POST /api/test/
testRouter.
    Handle("/", rootHandler(create)).
    Methods("POST")

// GET /api/test/{id}/
testRouter.
    HandleFunc("/{id:[0-9]+}/", rootHandler(getByID)).
    Methods("GET")
```

```
func create(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    // CustomError implementes error
    return &CustomError{
        Kind:       EPARSE,
        Status:     http.StatusBadRequest,
        Message:    "some message",
        Op:         "create",
        Err:        err,
    }
}
```

This worked very well, but I would prefer not to wrap every controller method (`create` in this case) in `rootHandler`, and figured the best way is to figure out some sort of post-middleware. I've failed at trying to create a post-middlewhere which the router uses instead of each controller method, and wondering how you may go about implementing this. The closest answer on SO I could find was emmbee's answer on [How can I combine Go middleware pattern with error returning request handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871194/how-can-i-combine-go-middleware-pattern-with-error-returning-request-handlers) except for fn in AuthMiddleware would be a controller method.

So ideally, I would have the below handler which handles the `CustomError` if it exists

```
// POST /api/test
testRouter.
    Handle("/", create).
    Methods("POST")
```

For context, I'm using gorilla mux and negroni.

Any ideas are appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't post image of texts; post the texts themselves instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ideal solution will not work. The mux API supports `http.Handler` and `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)` arguments.  You have a `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error`.  A `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error` cannot be passed as one of the argument types supported by the mux API.

The only solution is to adapt each controller function to a type supported by the mux API using the `rootHandler` wrapper.  The wrapper does not add overhead compared to the standard `http.HandlerFunc` wrapper.

Use a helper function to reduce the amount of code required for the wrappers:

```
func handle(r *mux.Router, p string, fn func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error) *mux.Route {
    return r.Handle(path, rootHandler(fn))
}

...
handle(testRouter, "/", create).Methods("POST")
handle(testRouter, "/{id:[0-9]+}/", getByID).Methods("GET")
```

Use a type switch in the helper function to handle different controller types:

```
func handle(r *mux.Router, p string, h interface{}) *mux.Route {
    switch h := h.(type) {
    case func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error:
        return r.Handle(p, rootHandler(h))
    case func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request):
        return r.HandleFunc(p, h)
    case http.Handler:
        return r.Handle(p, h)
    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("handler type %T not supported", h))
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution for the issue I described. Thanks for adding a detailed explanation.